# remove quartz trigger that will not run again

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

Does the quartz scheduler remove the triggers that won't run again or we should remove them ourselves by using the RemoveTrigger method. I want to run a job at an instance of time but after execution that job won't run again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by default Quartz will remove triggers that are complete (will not fire again). You do not need to remove them manually unless you've set up a trigger that will never expire, like a CronTrigger, for example.

Comment: For anyone interested, the same is true of Quartz.NET.

Comment: What about a CronTrigger with a specified end time? Will that be removed / cleaned up?

Comment: @face, did you figure out the answer to your question eventually?

Answer (score 1):

If you scheduled your job using a SimpleTrigger, then you don't need to remove it manually.

If you want to check it by yourself, the way is to configure Quartz to use a database store, so that you can run a query against the triggers table.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html

Comment: Please note that in this case, the repeat count of your SimpleTrigger must be finite (so don't use the REPEAT_INDEFINITELY enumeration).